# NSCountedSet order by count

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscountedset

Does anyone know how to take an NSCountedSet of objects and create an array of those objects in order by their object count? (highest count to lowest)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array2];

    NSMutableArray *dictArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [countedSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [dictArray addObject:@{@"object": obj,
                               @"count": @([countedSet countForObject:obj])}];
    }];

    NSLog(@"Objects sorted by count: %@", [dictArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO]]]);
```

In the code above, `array2` is an array of of 100 random strings, each with two letters. `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`, returns a sorted array, in this case it is sorted in descending order by the count of the objects.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to achieve the same result:

```
NSArray *sortedValues = [countedSet.allObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSUInteger n = [countedSet countForObject:obj1];
    NSUInteger m = [countedSet countForObject:obj2];
    return (n <= m)? (n < m)? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedSame : NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

To get the values in descending order you could use (or reverse the above return value).

```
sortedValues.reverseObjectEnumerator.allObjects
```

Comment: If you change `return (n <= m)? (n < m)? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedSame : NSOrderedDescending;` for `return (n <= m)? (n < m)? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame : NSOrderedAscending;` you get highest to lowest.

Comment: This is a good answer but I prefer to use `NSNumber` instances for each of the countForObject values and then just return the `compare` result for those.

Answer (score 5):

For Swift3 you need to modify the provided swift code a bit:

```
let countedSet = [1,2,2,4,6,7,8,8,5,8,1]

let sorted = countedSet.allObjects.sorted { return countedSet.count(for: $0.0) > countedSet.count(for: $0.1) }

// iterate over all items in the set
for item in countedSet {
    print("\(item): Count - \(countedSet.count(for: item))")
}
```

Comment: What's up with the `bag` reference? Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I tested the code with other variable names and renamed the variable wrong ;-) It adapted the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Swift version:

```
let sorted = countedSet.allObjects.sort { return countedSet.countForObject($0.0) < countedSet.countForObject($0.1) }
```

Just change the `<` to `>` for descending order